# Get Randoms Columns as a List of String

Tags: java, string, list

With the below code, I am trying to get the values of the columns delimited by comma in `columnsList String` which works perfectly fine-

```
final String columnsList = getColumns(service.getColumns());

private String getColumns(final List<String> columns) {
    List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(columns);
    Collections.shuffle(copy);

    int rNumber = random.nextInt(columns.size()) + 1;

    List<String> subList = copy.subList(0, rNumber);
    Collections.sort(subList, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return columns.indexOf(o1) < columns.indexOf(o2) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });
    return StringUtils.join(subList, ",");
}
```

Now I need to change the above `getColumns` method in such a way, instead of returning `various columns` delimited by `comma` as a String it should return me back various columns as a `List<String>`. So one way I thought of doing is like this by using `Arrays.asList`-

`final List<String> columnsList = Arrays.asList(getColumns(service.getColumns()).trim().split(","));`

But I am looking for some other way by which I should be able to modify `getColumns` method such that it always returns back the `columns as a List of String` instead of doing the way I am doing currently with `Arrays.asList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this as simple as just returning sublist or am I missing something

```
private List<String> getColumns(final List<String> columns) {
    List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(columns);
    Collections.shuffle(copy);

    int rNumber = random.nextInt(columns.size()) + 1;

    List<String> subList = copy.subList(0, rNumber);
    Collections.sort(subList, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return columns.indexOf(o1) < columns.indexOf(o2) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });
    return subList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by replacing `return StringUtils.join(subList, ",");` with `return subList;`